# Difference Between two list of list

Tags: python, list

```
temp1= [["1","2"],["9","12"],['13',"14"],['16',"17"],['111','123']]
temp2 = [["1","2"],["9","12"],['13','14'],['16',"17"]]
```

I want the difference b/w these two list of list

output should be:[['111', '123']]

Please Help me out in this, Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: We can help, but we expect to see traces of your attempts, and where you are stuck

Comment: `[x for x in temp1 if x not in temp2] + [x for x in temp2 if x not in temp1]` - This would do